# yii2 multiple database authentication

Tags: authentication, yii2, authorization

I don't know if it sounds stupid or duplicated question. But I'm trying to move to multiple databases in my project. Each company should have a particular database. And each company should have different type of users (I mean users who have different roles). All databases have same structure but different data. Is this possible to jump to another database? If it is, how?

Answer (score 1):

Are possible several ways

a way is based on different db componente declaration in you confing

```
  return [
      'components' => [
         'db_default' => [
              'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
              'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb_default',
              'username' => 'my_username_default',
              'password' => 'my_password_default',
          ],
          'db1' => [
              'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
              'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb1',
              'username' => 'my_username1',
              'password' => 'my_password1',
          ],
          'db2' => [
              'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
              'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb2',
              'username' => 'my_username2',
              'password' => 'my_password2',
          ],
          ....


      ],
  ];
```

then you can extend  all your Class  redefining the getDb function

```
  class Customer extends ActiveRecord
  {
      // ...

      public static function getDb()
      {
          //  you could check some application condition for get the db you need 
          // use the "db2" application component
          switch ($my_condition) {
            case 'condition_1':
                 return \Yii::$app->db1;  
              break;
             case 'condition_2':
                 return \Yii::$app->db2;  
              break;               
            default:
                 return \Yii::$app->db_default;  
              break;
          }

      }
  }
```

another way is create the connection to db dinamically

```
if (isset(Yii::$app->db)){
    Yii::$app->db->close()
  }

  Yii::$app->db= \yii\db\Connection([
      // dsn user and password are from session, set these value during login procedure
      'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_act_dbname',
      'username' => 'your_act_username',
      'password' => 'your_act_password,
  ]);


$models = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM your_table')
            ->queryAll();
```

In $models you should have all  the models of the table selected from the database assigned in Connection
You can check the contents of $models eg: using var_dump($models)

Comment: Do me a little favor man. Describe how to change dynamically??

Comment: when you need  to connect another database you can close() the open connectio and create a new one  .. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html

Comment: I'm doing this: 
`echo Yii::$app->db->dsn;
$db = Yii::$app->db;
$db->close();
$db->dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sherik';
$db->username = 'root';
$db->password = '123';
$db->charset = 'utf8';
$db->open();` But still not working. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i have added  the code for a connection and the use the connection for select from  a table and get the result in $models .. hope is clear ..

Comment: Your are saying about getting particular table from another database?

Comment: my sample select for the table named your_table form the database assigne in dns (act_dbname) in the connection params .. hope is clear ..

Comment: I'm not trying to get data from another database. I'm trying to jump to another database, I mean move to another database. In you sample I should perform lot's of checking in my project. What I'm asking is is there any way to move another database, so my project works completely with next database. My all databases have same structure but different data

Comment: if you have two database then create two connection one  for db1 and one for db2 and use the proper connection ..otherwise  take a look at fisrt part of answer  where yiu can use different db based on components

Comment: change connection dns dbname  means change (jump to another)  database  .. ii suggest uyou some basic course for db access using PDO /DAO in php and then try to use Yii2  db connection components